server-side request cant access token. token undefined error
This section code must read the token and approve the login process. But it can`t read tokens from my cookie.
app.get("/get-token", (req, res) => {
    // Get the access token from cookies
    console.log("Cookies:", req.cookies); // Debugging cookies
    const accessToken = req.cookies["access_token"];

    if (!accessToken) {
        console.error("Token not found in cookies:", req.cookies["access_token"]);
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized. No Token Provided" });
    }

    verifyToken(accessToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
        .then((decoded) => {
            console.log("Token successfully verified. Decoded payload:", decoded);
            res.json({ token: decoded.name, isAdmin: decoded.isAdmin });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Token verification failed:", err.message);
            res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized. Invalid Token" });
        });
});

// Utility function to verify the token using Promises
function verifyToken(token, secretKey) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(decoded);
            }
        });
    });
} 


In this code /get-token request can't access my token in the cookie. It returns return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized. No Token Provided" });. How can I fix this?
A cookie is stored in the browser, but the server side cannot access this cookie.
in this code /get-token request can't access my token in the cookie. It returns this error
"return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized. No Token Provided" });"

How can I fix this?

Are you using Use Cookie Parser?

Hi, Is it a same-site or cross-site access ?

There next places that might have errors:

Does console.log("Cookies:") have your cookie?
If not, make sure there is app.use(cookieParser()); above the app.get.
Does jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, decoded) receive all required data? Try logging parameters and check if there are any undefined values.
Can jwt.verify verify your data? Try calling it directly.

Browsers send cookies to the server if the cookies match the domain of the request. For example, cookies set for example.com are sent with requests to example.com, but not to other domains.
